# Tkinter winfo_interps always empty

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

Why does winfo_interps always return an empty tuple ?

The [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TkCmd/winfo.html#M18) states:

> Returns a list whose members are the names of all Tcl interpreters
> (e.g. all Tk-based applications) currently registered for a particular
> display. If the -displayof option is given then the return value
> refers to the display of window; otherwise it refers to the display of
> the application's main window.

and the source code is:

```
def winfo_interps(self, displayof=0):
    """Return the name of all Tcl interpreters for this display."""
    args = ('winfo', 'interps') + self._displayof(displayof)
    return self.tk.splitlist(self.tk.call(args))
```

While displayof and splitlist works in other calls, this one wont work. I assume it is related to the tcl interpreter. I'm running the following code under Windows 11 in python 3.10 and tkinter 8.6.12

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
inps = tk.Tcl()
print(root.winfo_interps())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "won't work" mean in this context? When I run this code on my machine I get  a tuple with one value.

Comment: @BryanOakley My tuple is empty. However, wouldn't you expect 2? One for the standalone and one for the tkinter interpreter.

Comment: Personally, I would expect one. You're calling the command on `root`, and `root` should only have a single interpreter attached to it. The app as a whole probably has two interpreters, one attached to the root window and one that isn't attached to any windows. To be honest, though, I've never used this command in tkinter before.

Comment: @BryanOakley So at least in my environment it seems to be something wrong. As a side note, I do not have any practical use case yet. But I did assume that display refers to the screen and there could be a practical use case in the future. In addition there seems to be no open issue to this feature, therefore I did open one. In case someone looking for it in the future or find an answer in spared time.

Comment: On Windows 10 I get an empty tuple as well. As @BryanOakley says only one entry would be expected with root (btw for this test ```root.mainloop()``` is not really necessary)

Comment: @Thingamabobs "But I did assume that display refers to the screen". ```display``` refers to the path of whichever window ```winfo``` is taking information about. In this case it is the app main window ```root``` as the default.

Comment: @InhirCode thanks for confirming the issue under Windows. Seems like I misunderstood the [displayof](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/WindowId.html) but it's quite undocumented. So as it seems the case that it refers to the interpreter attached to the window, I wonder how this command could be ever useful. At least in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is indeed always empty on Windows. This is correct; the IPC mechanism that sits behind it is not supported on that platform (for a mixture of technical and historic policy reasons relating to the state of Windows's security a few decades ago). There are various alternative solutions (such as OLE or COM or something based on sockets), but none are enabled by default and all are a bit annoying when it comes to discovery. I don't know the space of Python solutions for this very well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this issue. I'm aware of many different ways for IPC on Windows. But I did hoped for a built in and cross platform way for tkinter applications, cause Tkinter offers many hidden useful feature I haven't discovered yet. BTW does this mean that `send` is disabled on Windows? Cause the tcl documentation warns for an security hole.

Comment: Correct; `send` being disabled is part of the same picture. It was classically built on X11 properties set on the root window, but that concept's meaningless on Windows and the alternatives had tricky security implications back in the day. Those haven't been as big a worry since Windows XP became common! The workarounds I know are all very Tcl-based, so can't really be easily applied to Tkinter in a useful way, and tend to have much more awkward discovery (e.g., COM impinges on the registry and assumes persistent services).