Open the running process in the background (systray) with the pinned Taskbar app using Python & Windows
I've been trying to implement some Windows native functionality using tkinter, pystray and threading and some extra needed libraries unsuccessfully.
I'm trying to achieve this functionality:

The systray icon, this is already done, mostly managed in run_tray_icon
The process should not open again once it's running (there should never be two processes of this program at the same time because they can conflict). For this, I've implemented an "app lock" functionality, handling all possible exits to remove the app lock with handle_exit, still sometimes I find that some processes are never closed and end running
I'm using some Queues in process_gui_queuebecause I feel that without them, some processes end in the background.
And finally, and the most difficult part, I have found no documentation so far on how to accomplish: Windows has the possibility of pinning apps to the task bar. If the process is running in the background, thanks to threading and hidden in try with pystray, if I click the pinned taskbar icon, it tries to open a new process, instead of doing a deiconify.

The standard behavior of a task bar pinned icon, is a process run. Basically, I should be able to access the running process, to run the root.deiconify but I don't have a clue on how I can achieve this feature.
This is the whole code I've been using for testing purposes, I have decided not to omit anything because I feel that everything is intertwined.
import os
import sys
import atexit
import signal
from pystray import Icon, Menu, MenuItem
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from queue import Queue
from ctypes import windll

LOCK_FILE = 'app.lock'
exit_flag = False
gui_queue = Queue()

def remove_lock_file():
    """Remove the lock file on exit."""
    if os.path.exists(LOCK_FILE):
        os.remove(LOCK_FILE)

def is_already_running():
    """Check if the application is already running."""
    if os.path.exists(LOCK_FILE):
        return True
    else:
        with open(LOCK_FILE, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(os.getpid()))
        return False

def handle_exit(signum=None, frame=None):
    """Handle exit signals."""
    global exit_flag
    exit_flag = True
    remove_lock_file()
    
# To ensure that Lock File is always removed we register special exit signal handlers
# SIGINT is sent when the user presses Ctrl+C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
# SIGTERM is sent when the system is shutting down
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
# SIGTERM is sent when the system is shutting down
signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, handle_exit)

def run_tray_icon(root):
    def show_window():
        gui_queue.put(lambda: root.deiconify())

    def hide_window():
        gui_queue.put(lambda: root.withdraw())

    def exit_application(icon, item):
        handle_exit()
        icon.stop()  # Stop the icon loop

    menu = Menu(
        MenuItem('Show', show_window),
        MenuItem('Hide', hide_window),
        MenuItem('Exit', exit_application)
    )
    
    def create_image(width, height, color1, color2):
        # Generate an image and draw a pattern
        image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color1)
        dc = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        dc.rectangle(
            (width // 2, 0, width, height // 2),
            fill=color2)
        dc.rectangle(
            (0, height // 2, width // 2, height),
            fill=color2)
        return image

    def run_icon():
        icon = Icon("Windows Tester", icon=create_image(64, 64, 'black', 'white'), menu=menu)
        icon.run()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_icon)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

def create_main_window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Windows Tester")
    root.geometry("300x200")
    
    # Modify close event to hide the window instead of closing the app
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: root.withdraw())

    return root

def process_gui_queue(root):
    """Quit the GUI event loop if the exit flag is set."""
    while not gui_queue.empty():
        action = gui_queue.get()
        action()

    if not exit_flag:
        root.after(100, process_gui_queue, root)
    else:
        root.quit()  # Stop the main loop

def start_gui_event_loop(root):
    process_gui_queue(root)
    root.mainloop()

def main():
    # Check if another instance is running
    if is_already_running():
        print("Another instance is already running.")
        sys.exit(0)

    # Register cleanup function
    atexit.register(remove_lock_file)

    # Set the App User Model ID
    try:
        myappid = 'sirlouen.windows-testing.0.0.1'
        windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to set App User Model ID: {e}")
    
    root = create_main_window()

    # Start the system tray icon in a separate thread
    run_tray_icon(root)
    
    # Start the GUI event loop
    start_gui_event_loop(root)

    # Perform cleanup
    remove_lock_file()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

One extra thing. To check the behavior, I'm using pyinstaller to:

Generate the exe
Pin it in the taskbar
Execute and hide it
Try to re-execute it from pinned icon in the task bar

pyinstaller --onefile main.py
PS: It's also killing me that to test each change, it takes like 2-3 minutes to generate another new EXE with this command.

You need to use absolute path for the app lock file and put that file in system temporary directory.

Not related to your problem, but if the device powers off, LOCK_FILE will never be deleted, so the program can't be started again until the user manually deletes the file.

@TheLizzard in fact after a long though, I believe that the LOCK_FILE itself doesnt solve the issue. I've been researching options, and the thing here is that the program doesnt actually check if there is a process with the ID in the lock_file, so the lock_file mechanism the way I've done it's useless. Also, the new process should be able to communicate with the old process once it reads the ID in the lock_file and tell the old process to deiconify. So now I need to search for this communication mechanism in Windows with Python. I've tried Tkinter winfo_interps and doesnt work with Windows

After a ton of researching, I tried each single idea that I found out there, from the winfo_interps to trying to manage with some Windows libraries with the win32 package and a lock file state like I showed in my first code.
The most important thing, I think I missed in my first part, is the fact that clicking on a Taskbar pinned icon actually opens an entirely new process. So this new process has to find the way to communicate with the previously initialized process living in the system tray.
Tkinter happens to have built-in functionality, where you can call an initialized object method in another process if you happen to define the name of the Tkinter object. But for some reason, Windows doesn't support this mechanism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73986115/4442122
So the solution here was implementing sockets with the python socket library, which happens to have, similarly to Tkinter call, a mechanism to send a method to a previously initialized object in such socket implementation.
Modifying the previous code, to remove all the LOCK_FILE references I made this new code:
from pystray import Icon, Menu, MenuItem
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import socket
from ctypes import windll

LISTEN_PORT = 21345

class WindowsTester(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(className='WindowsTester')
        self.title("Windows Tester")
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="This is a Tkinter app!")
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)
        self.start_server()
        
    def start_server(self):
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_server)
        self.server_thread.daemon = True
        self.server_thread.start()

    def run_server(self):
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_socket.bind(('localhost', LISTEN_PORT))
        server_socket.listen(1)  # Listen for incoming connections
        while True:
            conn, addr = server_socket.accept()  # Accept a connection
            print('Connected by', addr)
            message = conn.recv(1024).decode()  # Receive the message
            print('Received:', message)
            if message == 'activate':
                self.activate()  # Call activate method
            conn.close()  # Close the connection
        
    def on_close(self):
        self.withdraw()  # Hide the window instead of destroying it
        
    def activate(self):
        self.deiconify()  # Show the window
        self.lift()  # Bring the window to the foreground

def run_tray_icon(root):
    def show_window():
        root.activate()

    def hide_window():
        root.on_close()

    def exit_application(icon):
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            client_socket.connect(('localhost', LISTEN_PORT))  # Connect to the server
            client_socket.sendall(b'exit')  # Send the exit message
            print("Exiting application")
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("No running instance found")
        finally:
            client_socket.close()  # Close the client socket
        icon.stop()  # Stop the icon loop

    menu = Menu(
        MenuItem('Show', show_window),
        MenuItem('Hide', hide_window),
        MenuItem('Exit', exit_application)
    )
    
    def create_image(width, height, color1, color2):
        image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color1)
        dc = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        dc.rectangle((width // 2, 0, width, height // 2), fill=color2)
        dc.rectangle((0, height // 2, width // 2, height), fill=color2)
        return image

    def run_icon():
        icon = Icon("Windows Tester", icon=create_image(64, 64, 'black', 'white'), menu=menu)
        icon.run()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_icon)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

def main():  
    # Try to connect to an existing instance
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        client_socket.connect(('localhost', LISTEN_PORT))  # Connect to the server
        client_socket.sendall(b'activate')  # Send the activate message
        print("Activated existing instance")
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("No existing instance found, starting a new one")
        
        try:
            myappid = 'sirlouen.windows-testing.0.0.1'
            windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to set App User Model ID: {e}")
        
        # Start a new instance
        root = WindowsTester()

        # Start the system tray icon in a separate thread
        run_tray_icon(root)
        
        # Start the GUI event loop
        root.mainloop()
    finally:
        print("Closing client socket")
        client_socket.close()  # Close the client socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Maybe it could be greatly improved because I have not read the full docs for sockets and there are things I'm missing, but I feel it's a nice starting boilerplate to initialize a Windows app with systray and taskbar functionality.
